# Problema URL webservices Prestashop

Tags: php, .htaccess, prestashop

Estoy intentando hacer uso del webservice de prestashop para realizar un pedido completo. He desarrollado un módulo y lo he probado con éxito en una tienda instalada de manera local.

El problema lo tengo al implementar el mismo módulo en la tienda real. He activado los servicios web, generado la api key y marcado para realizar las pruebas las casillas correspondientes a customers. Vale, pues al realizar una simple consulta de este modo `http://www.midominio.com/api/customers` la web se redirecciona al frontpage de la tienda.

He comprobado el `.htaccess` y activado `rewrite_rules` en apache y nada, no consigo que me devuelva un archivo XML.

Os dejo por aquí la configuración de mi `.htaccess`:

```
# ~~start~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
# .htaccess automaticaly generated by PrestaShop e-commerce open-source solution
# http://www.prestashop.com - http://www.prestashop.com/forums

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_env.c>
        SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    </IfModule>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}] 

#Domain: www.mydomain.com
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
RewriteRule ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 [L]
</IfModule>

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|svg)$">
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

#If rewrite mod isn't enabled
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?controller=404

# ~~end~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vale, problema encontrado. La web trabajaba por detrás con un Nginx que tenia una regla location en el archivo de configuración que redireccionaba todas las URL (incluida /api/loquesea) al index.php.

Gracias a todos. Tema cerrado.

Comment: Buenas @Makros, ¿La web está entonces sobre apache pero trabaja también con Nginx? ¿Con algún tipo de solicitud webservice o de qué tipo?

Comment: La web la han montado sobre nginx pero el servidor tenía además un apache que me estaba trolleando. Finalmente era la configuración de Nginx. El problema era que Nginx tenia una regla que toda URL que no fuera las "Oficiales" en la tienda PS las redirigía siempre a index.php. He añadido una regla para la url /api/loquesea y solucionado.

Comment: Márcalo como solucionado :(

Comment: Disculpa @DanielDíaz, no recordaba esta entrada. Ya está marcado.